# Android Facebook SDK - HelloFacebookSample "Pick some friends" option displays empty screen

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-3.1

Running a freshly installed Facebook SDK v3.15.0 for Android, clicking "Pick Some Friends" button, launched the facebook friends picker, but shows no friends at all.
I'de expect it to show a list of all my friends, letting me pick one.

Suggestions?

Comment: have you configured your developer account in fb?? and i recommend you use easyfacebook.jar its really simple because fb official sdk is s***

Comment: @IllegalArgument Well, I have a few apps in production. Do I have to define something for the sample app as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On April 2014, Facebook have made a breaking change to "friends list" functionality.

In short, when an application requests a list of the user's friends, it will only get back **the list of friends that are also using the same app, and logged-in to facebook using it.**
It also requires a new permission 'user_friends' that should be asked for when logging the user in.

Thus, the lists comes up empty, as none of my friends are using the sample app.

Note: this change of API is breaking the most basic social feature i.e. "list of my friends".
In addition, it breaks simple applications such as a "birthday reminder".

Facebook is allowing access to the old API (which does allow listing of all friends) until April 2015.
Let's hope they realize they made a mistake by then, and change the semantics to how it was before.

Comment: Thanks @Guy. For anyone interested, Facebook's official info on this is [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.1).  Look for the **user_friends** permission.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try the ***Request*** mechanism, which supports the ability to send invites to friends. It is geared mostly towards gaming, but supports some good use cases. More info can be found [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests/v2.1).